# Minimum sound power required at iPhone 5 microphone?

Tags: core-audio, iphone-5

I'm writing an Objective C iOS app which will react to specific sounds.

What is the minimum sound power that the iPhone (5,5c,5s) microphone must sense in order to do audio
acquisition?

Answer (score 0):

There is no minimum sound power - you can initiate recording at any time. There are multiple ways to do this depending on exactly what you want to do, but the simplest is through the AV Foundation Framework. If you need more control you can use the Core Audio Framework, which provides a very powerful set of tools but is more complicated. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH9-SW2.

But maybe this isn't exactly what you're asking? If you're asking is there some way to have your app "come alive" and start recording when a certain dB level is reached, there is no way to do that. You need to have the app constantly running and recording, and monitor the sound yourself.